# Support iOS 4 and 5 Webview scroll delegate

Tags: objective-c, ios5, uiwebview, uiscrollview, uiscrollviewdelegate

I made an application for iPhone/iPad that uses a Webview.
When i scroll at the top of my Webview, a panel opens (like in the Google app).

To get the Webview scroll delegate I'm using that code :

```
for(UIView * subView in webView.subviews){
    if ([subView isKindOfClass:[UIScrollView class]]) {
        webViewScroll = (UIScrollView *)subView;
        webViewScrollDefaultDelegate = webViewScroll.delegate;
        [webViewScroll setDelegate:self];
    }
}
```

To manage the scroll, I use those functions :

```
-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView    
-(void)scrollViewDidEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView willDecelerate:(BOOL)decelerate
```

I need the default delegate because I don't know what viewForZoomingInScrollView should return from the scroll of the webview.

```
-(UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    if(scrollView == webViewScroll){
        return [webViewScrollDefaultDelegate viewForZoomingInScrollView:scrollView];
    }
    return nil;
}
```

It's working well in iOS 4. But in iOS 5, when I call webViewScroll.delegate, it returns 0x0 (nil)  and the zoom do not work anymore...

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible the API functionality for it changed a bit between the two versions of iOS. My guess is you could have a conditional to run it slightly differently in the case of iOS 5? (If you can get it to work properly in a separate code segment)

Answer (score 0):

If you turn on ARC in your iOS 5 application check scroll view property settings. IBOutlet get `(nonatomic, weak)`